# Can I use feature detection to know if css hover works for this client?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I've got a website that provides labels when the user hovers over an image. You can see the example at: http://www.185vfx.com/

For touchscreens, I'd like to have those hints on by default (since hover isn't usually available). I'd prefer not to browser-sniff and try to maintain that list as new devices/versions arrive.

Any reliable way to detect if a browser can respond to hover or otherwise know about a touchscreen user via javascript or css?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Even if they do have a touchscreen, they might be using a mouse anyway. For that matter, whether they have a touchscreen or not, they might be using a keyboard (or a breath switch or something else) to navigate and still be unable to hover.

It is best not to put important information behind a hover reveal in the first place (or at least to always provide another means to access it).

Comment: Yes, that page is a bit of a "mystery meat" menu.  It's not clear that each picture is supposed to represent, apparently, a blog entry.